# Excel Store Inventory Formula

Tags: excel, stock

I am stuck for couples of days in generate an Excel Formula, I would appreciate your help guys

I have machines need specific materials to be erected 
eg. machine "A" needs M1: 2 pcs , M4= 3 pcs ...etc.

I also have stock for the available materials and their Qty

[image: Machine List and Stock]

Now I need to assign Materials to each machine based on the following Conditions:

1. if the qty needed more than the existed in the stock I will not issue
   eg. Machine A needs 4pcs of M4, and the available is 3,it will be a shortage and the results in stock will remain 3
2. if the machine I am checking has one or more previous component as shortage I will not issue material for it

   the result suppose to be as the below Table

   [image: Results]

I need to do this using Excel and not Excel VBA

I would really appreciate your help

Comment: What are you stuck with exactly? Not sure exactly what formulas you need, but things like `=VLOOKUP(B2, E3:F4, 2, FALSE)` for getting your stock from the formula, and `=IF(C2>D2, D2-C2, "")`,

Comment: The Lookup will get me the Initial Stock Balance 
however it's changing since I am issuing materials for each machine

Comment: Where do you specify that you have issued for a machine then? Do you need the stock to update when its issued?

Comment: Where is the `Inital Stoe`, `Store Balnce Update`, and `Shortage` numbers coming from?

Comment: I apologies guys if my post was not clear 
I am trying to distribute materials from the stock to the machine
so the stock should be updated whenever I am issuing or not 

and the initial store  Value comes from the physical check 
the store Balance update which is the value after each material disruption 
the shortage which is the Qty in stock - the required Qty

Comment: The problem is that for the `Inital Stoe`, there is no way of knowing at that time how much inventory is in the store unless you have time stamps of when inventory is added and when it gets used or something to indicate the order in which inventory is added and used.

Comment: now if I use this formula 
=Vlookup for initialvalueinstote - sumif(qty for all the above material)
it will give partial solution since it will take all the required material regarding if I issue or not
for example     
=VLOOKUP(F2,Store!C:D,2,0)-SUMIF($F$1:F2,F2,$G$1:G2),0)